# Исключение в JQuery

Tags: jquery-ui, javascript

Нужно выводить все данные из `.threadNametd`, в которых нет тега b(<b></b>).

Исключением не получилось, выводит всё равно всё.

```
$('.threadNametd').not('b').each( function() {
    $('.threadNametd').each( function() {
        theme_name = $(this).find('.forum').text();
        template_normal_themes += theme_name+'|';
    });
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Примерчик [смотрите тут](http://jsfiddle.net/Deonis/5qKXE/3/). У вас должно быть что-то вроде:

```
var template_normal_themes = $('.threadNametd').filter(':not(:has("b"))').map(function(){
    return $(this).text();
}).get().join(' | ');
$('#output').text(template_normal_themes);
```

Answer (score 3):

Изначально вы меня запутали своим предположением. Ваша задача не так решается.

Вы неправильно применяете **[.not](http://api.jquery.com/not/)**. У вас же явно не тэги **b** с классом **.threadNametd** в верстке?

**.not** исключает из выборки *определенного вида тэгов* (например, li), *такие же тэги* по определенному условию. Сюда подойдет любой селектор, которым можно выбрать такой тэг.

Насколько мне известно, селекторами можно вытянуть тэг с определенным родителем **ul > li**, но не с определенным потомком. Поэтому **использование [.not](http://api.jquery.com/not/) тут бесполезно**.

**[решение](http://jsfiddle.net/venzell/shHrs/)**

```
var filtered = $('.threadNametd');

filtered.each(function() {
    var there_is_no_b = $(this).find('b').length === 0,    
    html = $(this).html();

    if (there_is_no_b) {
        //Do something
        console.log(html);
    } else {
        console.log(html + ' <-- "b" here');
    }

});
```

**тестовый html-код**

```
<p class="threadNametd"><span>Hello</span>, how are you?</p>
<p class="threadNametd">Me? I'm <span><b>good</b></span>.</p>
```

**результат**

```
<span>Hello</span>, how are you?
Me? I'm <span><b>good</b></span>. <-- "b" here
```

Comment: @VenZell, Ваше решение тоже игнорирует исключение.

Comment: Соберите, пожалуйста, какой-никакой пример. Не будем же мы гадать на кофейной гуще?